# (python bottle pyserial): monitor serial input while read and write data with a webapp

Tags: python, bottle, pyserial

i want to constantly monitor a serial port, write its data (events) somewhere and send values to it. it works without the "web part".

i am playing with "bottle". to be able to check if everything is working, i wanted to write the serial devices data to file, and log the web request there, too. as this is not working, do you have

- any hint what i am doing wrong?
- i am not shure if my approach to bring my device to the web :-) is wokring like this, so i would appreciate any ideas.

  ```
  @post('/art/control/serial/')
  def artControlSerial():
  import serial.tools.list_ports #https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

  req_obj = request.body.read()
  print(req_obj)

  arduinoport = 'COM4'

  try:
      ser = serial.Serial(arduinoport,57600,timeout=0.01)

  except serial.SerialException as e:
      print("could not open serial port '{}': {}".format(arduinoport, e))
  return        

  while True:


      #send 2 serial
      senddata = req_obj
      ser.write(senddata.encode())

      newline = 'a new line'
      f = open('F:/test/logs/serial.log','w')
      f.write(newline)
      f.close

      ser.flush()
      ser.flushInput()
      ser.flushOutput()

  #callback message
  return 'message written to serial port'
  ```

thanks, 
tbz

Answer (score 0):

I've done a project where you can controll an engine trough a web interface. I've found out that you need to setup your serial connection apart, because every time you make a request you're restarting your serial connection.